# Python: Converting keys in dictionary to day of the week which can repeat

Tags: python, collections

I have a dictionary where keys and values are string. Keys looks like date and values like integers:

```
('04 Aug, 2019','1 '),
('26 Apr, 2019','6 '),
...
```

So each date has own value. Now I want to convert this dates to day of the week and sum this values for each day. The problem is when I use `datetime.strptime` to convert, my dictionary is cut because of repeated keys. Keys were converting like:

```
converted_days = [datetime.strptime(d,"%d %b, %Y").strftime("%A") for d in days]
```

This allow me to represent this string: '04 Aug, 2019' to day of the week. But for more than 7 keys, some keys will be repeated after converting. In addition, for each day I want to sum value, for example:

```
monday: 7
monday: 10
friday: 2
sunday: 5
sunday: 3
```

And insted of collection like above (which can't be created because of repeated keys), I want to get:

```
monday: 17
friday: 2
sunday: 8
```

In addition, dictionary is created by `dict(zip(x,y)` method, where x is a list of dates(as strings) and y is a list of integers(as strings). Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That's not a dictionary, the keys aren't dates (they're strings) and the values aren't integers (they're also strings). Please give a [mcve] that actually represents the problem you're trying to solve. Also note that dictionaries can only have one value for a given key, so if the same date appears multiple times you'll have to e.g. store the values as a list.

Comment: Please share the code that is causing you trouble, with some sensible inputs, show what the output is and describe the expected output.

Comment: I editted my question. I hope is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're after:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

days = [('04 Aug, 2019', '1 '), ('26 Apr, 2019', '6 '), ('19 Apr, 2019', '4 ')]

totals = defaultdict(int)
for date_str, value_str in days:
    totals[datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d %b, %Y").strftime("%A")] += int(value_str)

print(totals)
```

Results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Sunday': 1, 'Friday': 10})
```

The key part here is of course the `defaultdict`, since it allows you to add to a key that previously wasn't defined. You can of course also start with a dict that has the value `0` for each possible key in this case, since there are only ever 7 days in a week. But that would leave days that never occur in the data set to `0` and you may need to go clean those up afterwards, so I would prefer `defaultdict`.

This is using that solution:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

days = [('04 Aug, 2019', '1 '), ('26 Apr, 2019', '6 '), ('19 Apr, 2019', '4 ')]

totals = dict(zip(calendar.day_name, [0] * 7))
for date_str, value_str in days:
    totals[datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d %b, %Y").strftime("%A")] += int(value_str)

print(totals)
```

And the result:

```
{'Monday': 0, 'Tuesday': 0, 'Wednesday': 0, 'Thursday': 0, 'Friday': 10, 'Saturday': 0, 'Sunday': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, works as should. Just instead of list I use dictionary to store dates and values